# Error while curve fitting in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I need to fit the curve `y = K + B*exp{ a*(log x) + b*(log x)^2 + c*(log x)^3 }`. Where a, b, c, K, B are unknown parameters. I just have 5 data points which are,

```
x = c( 0.0, 5.4,  8.3, 12.0, 15.5)
y=c(0.547575, 0.915275, 1.520744, 2.335375, 2.505200)
```

I tried fitting the data in R using `nls` function but the value of the parameters don't converge. It shows the error:

> 'Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model'.

Comment: nls is not easy to use, most of the time you need to try different start values. Also check stackoverflow, this question is asked a lot of times there.

Comment: You have a zero in `x` and take the logarithm which is undefined. That needs to be addressed first.

Comment: If it might be of some use, my equation search showed that a Gunary equation with offset, "y = x / (a + b * x + c * pow(x, 0.5))" gave an excellent fit for parameters a = 7.3217026522412596E+01, b = 5.5401514090978958E+00, c = -3.8402239543268763E+01, and Offset = 5.4101808752330749E-01 yielding R-squared = 0.9998 and RMSE = 0.008831 no logs necessary.

Comment: @COOLSerdash The function at x=0 is the blank sample and represents the sample matrix, instrument and other noise factors.